# for loop has been crashed when uint=0

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

why this loop is infinite When I have tried to bottom code in flash with as3,

```
   for(var i:uint=10;i>=0;i--)
    {
        //some code
        trace(i);
    }
```

Here is the output;

```
10
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
0
4294967295
4294967294
4294967293
.
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have the answer in the [definition of `uint`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/uint.html) :

> The uint class provides methods for working with a data type representing a 32-bit unsigned integer. Because an unsigned integer can only be positive, its maximum value is twice that of the int class.

So this unsigned integer can only be positive and it's between `uint.MIN_VALUE`, which is `0`, and `uint.MAX_VALUE` which is `4294967295`. That's why your for loop will never finished because when `i == 0`, it will take the value `4294967295` which is surely greater than `0`, so the for loop condition is always true.

Comment: Adding $0.02: using `uint` is slower in AS3 than using plain `int`, and when traversing an array backwards you really need negative numbers in counter.